# powershell importexcel module conditional formatting

Tags: excel, powershell

I have been using the importexcel powershell module to generate some excel spreadsheets.

I am now trying to add some conditional formating.  How can I add formating so that if a cell (date) is greater then another cell (date) it sets the colour.

Sorry guys,  I am really nowhere with the code. There are not much examples around. I have a Date in a variable called $offlineDate.  If I call that command without the -conditionalText switch it is fine but I cant work out the syntax for conditionalText.  I already have another worksheet called sheet1 with some date values.

```
$offlineDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm") |
    Export-Excel -Path "C:\Users\cp542164\Desktop\BDP\test.xlsx" -WorkSheetname 'Date' -Show -AutoSize -conditionalText $(
        New-ConditionalText -Range "sheet1!$C$2:$D$391" -ConditionalType GreaterThan "Date!$A$1" -BackgroundColor Red
    )
```

See screenshot.[image: Excel Conditional formatting]

Comment: Show us a minimal code example and tell us what you have tried.

Comment: Your question doesn't contain any of the code you are using. Check out [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) for help with asking a great question that will get you a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

Sorted it out myself.  The issue was that I needed to use the $ sign to reference a excel cell and powershell thought I was referring to a variable.  Fixed it by escaping the $. Cant paste code.  The powershell escape character is not displaying.